# Trying to post comment to my post via curl and it doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl

I have a route

```
 POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)             comments#create
```

My comment has "content" field. Let's say I want to POST a comment to my post.

So I am trying to post a comment via curl doing this command
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"comment": "hello"}' http://localhost:3000/posts/2/comments

but I get an Action Controller: Exception caught

Not sure why

Controller

```
# POST /comments                                                                                                                                            
  # POST /comments.json                                                                                                                                       
  def create                                                                                                                                                  
    @comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)                                                                                                             

    respond_to do |format|                                                                                                                                    
      if @comment.save                                                                                                                                        
        format.html { redirect_to @comment, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }                                                                     
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @comment }                                                                                    
      else                                                                                                                                                    
        format.html { render :new }                                                                                                                           
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }                                                                           
      end                                                                                                                                                     
    end                                                                                                                                                       
  end           


# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.                                                                      
    def comment_params                                                                                                                                        
      params.require(:comment).permit(:comment)                                                                                                               
    end
```

EDIT:

```
error in log file
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `permit' for "hello":String):
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:89:in `comment_params'
  app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:33:in `create'
```

EDIT: 
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"comment":{"comment":"test"}}' http://localhost:3000/posts/8/comments

Worked for me but I am a bit confused why when I do similar curl for my POST:
`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"title":"funny title","content":"cool stuff", "user_id":2}' localhost:3000/posts` and my post params look like this `params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :user_id)`

Why that works without passing the post in the curl hash?

Comment: Hi - if you have an exception... that means your app will have generated a stacktrace - which is really useful in helping figure out what exactly went wrong. You'll usually find it in your server window, or your logfiles - and it's about 20-40 lines of listing of various files, with an error message at the very top. Find that, then edit your question and paste it all into there and we can help you figure out what went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're saying here is "for the comment object, permit the comment attribute"

```
params.require(:comment).permit(:comment)
```

so rails is expecting something like:

```
{"comment": {"comment": "hello"}}
```

if you want to quick-fix it -> you'll need to use the above for your data.
Otherwise you'll need to figure out what the data really would look like for a real comment-form, and update your require/permit line to match that

Comment: Yea my Comment model has a comment textarea attribute. That's how a data looks like? Do I have to pass comment: as a key because it's a nested route? because when I create my posts I do similar post curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"title":"funny title","content":"cool stuff", "user_id":2}' http://localhost:3000/posts and my post params look like this params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :user_id)

Comment: "comment": {"comment": "hello"}} didn't work for me either.. Error occurred while parsing request parameters. Contents: {comment:{comment:

Comment: curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"comment":{"comment":"test"}}' http://localhost:3000/posts/8/comments worked

Comment: Stack overflow comments don't have good code formatting - so if you tried that and got an error, can you edit your question and say what you've tried and give us the full error stacktrace again?

Comment: possibly you don't have a problem for posts because there isn't a "post" attribute (just title etc instead), and maybe rails is getting confused between the comment object and the comment attribute - and so that's why you need it for a comment but not a post?